# Why does it think screenWidth / 2 is the far right side of the screen?

Tags: ios

I'm pretty new to iOS development-- still in those early days of not knowing where to look to figure out what could be wrong.

So I have this:

```
#define kScreenWidth [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

And then I have this:

```
TileView* tile = [[TileView alloc] initWithLetter:letter andSideLength:tileSide];
tile.center = CGPointMake(kScreenWidth/2, 50);
[self.gameView addSubview:tile];
```

And then I run the simulator and the tile gets drawn wayyy off to the side. It's that little black `1` over there in the corner. But when I set the X value for the center to `0`, it appears against the far left side. So why would it think the middle was over there?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6? If so, you need to play around with the correct iPhone size and the corresponding simulator.

Comment: I NSLog'ed the screenWidth and it was 568. Not sure if that's right. What do you mean play around with the size?

Comment: Looks like you found your answer! What I saying is that I had a similar problem before. In Xcode IB, you have to set the correct iPhone size you are going to work with and then if you change the size or use a different simulator, the elements might be off...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got your width and height mixed up in the initial declaration of kScreenWidth

Comment: Wow. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes. LMAO. Bingo. Fixed.